# Using the $dropdown service (AngularStrap)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angularjs-directive, angular-strap

I'm having trouble using the AngularStrap `$dropdown` service. As the following [plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/du9uefYFyiPxPPBzJpib?p=preview) shows, I'm able to have it responding to events correctly, but I did not understand how to populate it using programmatic means (i.e., from a directive).

Here is the initialization snippet:

```
var dropdown = $dropdown(element, {
    content: "Hello",
    show: false,
    trigger: "manual"
});
```

I tried to mimic the way a popover (also given in the plunk as a reference) is filled, unsuccessfully. I also tried to set the `content` property with the value of `$scope.dropdown` (see [here](http://mgcrea.github.io/angular-strap/##dropdowns)), with no satisfactory outcome.

A complementary (but not blocking) issue also occured with the first call to `dropdown.hide()`, that irremediably causes a `TypeError: Cannot read property 'off' of undefined`, whereas the first `popover.hide()` runs silently. It might be an AngularStrap bug, but also a misuse.

Thanks by advance for the kind help!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working plunk that shows the context menu

http://plnkr.co/edit/tNAX7liFSNh71XcOUecs

```
var dropdown = $dropdown(element, {
            show: false,
            trigger: "manual",
            html: true
        });

  dropdown.$scope.content = [ 
      {
        "text": "<i class=\"fa fa-globe\"></i>&nbsp;Display an alert",
        "click": "alert(\"Holy guacamole!\")"
      },
      {
        "divider": true
      },
      {
        "text": "Separated link",
        "href": "#separatedLink"
      }
    ];

    element.on("contextmenu", function(event) {
      event.preventDefault();
          console.log("dropdown right click");
          scope.$apply(function() {
            scope.dropdown_show = true;
      });
    });
```

However, I am still trying to get the 'click' working.